# Consulta con 5 union

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo una consulta, tengo código `SQL`  un `union` donde consulto 5 tablas, el campo en común es la `fecha`, como puedo hacer para que me ordene por la fecha de una tabla de uno de esos unión específicos, acá dejo el código

```
SELECT 
          (t_evaluacion_mayor5.id, 
          t_evaluacion_mayor5.codigo_evaluacion, 
          ''::text AS codigo_seguimiento, 
          t_evaluacion_mayor5.codigo_persona, 
          t_evaluacion_mayor5.talla::text AS talla, 
          t_evaluacion_mayor5.peso::text AS peso, 
          ''::text AS peso_pregestacional, 
          ''::text AS peso_actual_emb, 
          ''::text AS ganancia_peso, 
          ''::text AS fecha_ultima_menstruacion, 
          ''::text AS semanas_gestacion, 
          ''::text AS cbi, 
          ''::text AS codigo_cbi_menor115, 
          ''::text AS edema_severo, 
          ''::text AS apetito, 
          t_evaluacion_mayor5.codigo_complicaciones_clinicas::text AS codigo_complicaciones_clinicas, 
          t_evaluacion_mayor5.codigo_estado_nutricional::text AS codigo_estado_nutricional, 
          t_evaluacion_mayor5.codigo_descripcion_situacion, 
          t_evaluacion_mayor5.fecha_abordaje, 
          t_evaluacion_mayor5.codigo_tipo_evaluacion, 
          t_evaluacion_mayor5.codigo_origen
     FROM dean_eapg.t_evaluacion_mayor5
    WHERE t_evaluacion_mayor5.codigo_descripcion_situacion::text > '1'::text
UNION 
     SELECT 
           t_evaluacion_menor5.id, 
           t_evaluacion_menor5.codigo_evaluacion, 
           ''::text AS codigo_seguimiento, 
           t_evaluacion_menor5.codigo_persona, 
           ''::text AS talla, 
           ''::text AS peso, 
           ''::text AS peso_pregestacional, 
           ''::text AS peso_actual_emb, 
           ''::text AS ganancia_peso, 
           ''::text AS fecha_ultima_menstruacion, 
           ''::text AS semanas_gestacion, 
           t_evaluacion_menor5.cbi::text AS cbi, 
           t_evaluacion_menor5.codigo_cbi_menor115::text AS codigo_cbi_menor115, 
           t_evaluacion_menor5.codigo_edema_severo::text AS edema_severo, 
           t_evaluacion_menor5.codigo_apetito::text AS apetito, 
           t_evaluacion_menor5.codigo_complicaciones_clinicas::text AS codigo_complicaciones_clinicas, 
           ''::text AS codigo_estado_nutricional, 
           t_evaluacion_menor5.codigo_descripcion_situacion::text AS codigo_descripcion_situacion, 
           t_evaluacion_menor5.fecha_abordaje, 
           t_evaluacion_menor5.codigo_tipo_evaluacion, 
           t_evaluacion_menor5.codigo_origen
       FROM dean_eapg.t_evaluacion_menor5
      WHERE t_evaluacion_menor5.codigo_descripcion_situacion::text > '1'::text
UNION 
      SELECT 
            t_evaluacion_embarazada.id, 
            t_evaluacion_embarazada.codigo_evaluacion, 
            ''::text AS codigo_seguimiento, 
            t_evaluacion_embarazada.codigo_persona, 
            ''::text AS talla, 
            ''::text AS peso, 
            t_evaluacion_embarazada.peso_pregestacional::text AS peso_pregestacional, 
            t_evaluacion_embarazada.peso_actual::text AS peso_actual_emb, 
            t_evaluacion_embarazada.incremento_peso::text AS ganancia_peso, 
            t_evaluacion_embarazada.fecha_ultima_menstruacion::text AS fecha_ultima_menstruacion, 
            t_evaluacion_embarazada.semanas_gestacion::text AS semanas_gestacion, 
            ''::text AS cbi, 
            ''::text AS codigo_cbi_menor115, 
            ''::text AS edema_severo, 
            ''::text AS apetito, 
            ''::text AS codigo_complicaciones_clinicas, 
            ''::text AS codigo_estado_nutricional, 
            t_evaluacion_embarazada.codigo_incremento_peso::text AS codigo_descripcion_situacion, 
            t_evaluacion_embarazada.fecha_abordaje, 
            t_evaluacion_embarazada.codigo_tipo_evaluacion, 
            t_evaluacion_embarazada.codigo_origen
  FROM dean_eapg.t_evaluacion_embarazada
  WHERE t_evaluacion_embarazada.codigo_incremento_peso::text > '1'::text
UNION 
   SELECT 
          t_evaluacion_menor3meses.id, 
          t_evaluacion_menor3meses.codigo_evaluacion, 
          ''::text AS codigo_seguimiento, 
          t_evaluacion_menor3meses.codigo_persona, 
          ''::text AS talla, 
          t_evaluacion_menor3meses.peso::text AS peso, 
          ''::text AS peso_pregestacional, 
          ''::text AS peso_actual_emb, 
          ''::text AS ganancia_peso, 
          ''::text AS fecha_ultima_menstruacion, 
          ''::text AS semanas_gestacion, 
          ''::text AS cbi, 
          ''::text AS codigo_cbi_menor115, 
          ''::text AS edema_severo, 
          ''::text AS apetito, 
          t_evaluacion_menor3meses.codigo_complicaciones_clinicas::text AS codigo_complicaciones_clinicas, 
          t_evaluacion_menor3meses.codigo_estado_nutricional::text AS codigo_estado_nutricional, 
          t_evaluacion_menor3meses.codigo_descripcion_situacion::text AS codigo_descripcion_situacion, 
          t_evaluacion_menor3meses.fecha_abordaje, 
          t_evaluacion_menor3meses.codigo_tipo_evaluacion, 
          t_evaluacion_menor3meses.codigo_origen
     FROM dean_eapg.t_evaluacion_menor3meses
    WHERE t_evaluacion_menor3meses.codigo_descripcion_situacion::text > '1'::text)
UNION 
 SELECT 
        t_seguimiento.id, 
        ''::text AS codigo_evaluacion, 
        t_seguimiento.codigo_seguimiento::text AS codigo_seguimiento, 
        t_seguimiento.codigo_persona, 
        t_seguimiento.talla::text AS talla, 
        t_seguimiento.peso::text AS peso, 
        ''::text AS peso_pregestacional, 
        ''::text AS peso_actual_emb, 
        t_seguimiento.ganancia_peso::text AS ganancia_peso, 
        ''::text AS fecha_ultima_menstruacion, 
        t_seguimiento.semanas_gestacion::text AS semanas_gestacion, 
        t_seguimiento.cbi::text AS cbi, 
        ''::text AS codigo_cbi_menor115, 
        t_seguimiento.edema_severo::text AS edema_severo, 
        t_seguimiento.apetito::text AS apetito, 
        t_seguimiento.complicacion_clinica::text AS codigo_complicaciones_clinicas, 
        ''::text AS codigo_estado_nutricional, 
        t_seguimiento.codigo_descripcion_situacion::text AS codigo_descripcion_situacion, 
        t_seguimiento.fecha_abordaje, 
        t_seguimiento.codigo_tipo_evaluacion, t_seguimiento.codigo_origen
   FROM dean_eapg.t_seguimiento
```

Necesito ordenar por fechas todas las tablas menos las seguimiento y que esas fechas de seguimiento las coloque al final, ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

> Necesito ordenar por fechas todas las tablas menos las seguimiento y que esas fechas de seguimiento las coloque al final

Mi interpretación de lo que quieres decir con esto es que deseas que el resultado de la unión de las 5 tablas esté ordenada por fecha, pero con la peculiaridad de que los registros provenientes de la tabla `t_seguimiento` deben aparecer después de los registros de las 4 otras tablas.

Si mi entendimiento es correcto, esto se puede lograr agregando una columna adicional a tus 5 selects para poder diferenciar los registros de la tabla `t_seguimiento`. Luego puedes agregar un `ORDER BY` al final que ordena por esa columna primero, y luego por fecha.

Ejemplo usando una versión muy simplificada de tu consulta:

```
select ...,
       fecha_abordaje,
       0 as seq
from t_evaluacion_mayor5
union
select ...,
       fecha_abordaje,
       0 as seq
from t_evaluacion_menor5
union
select ...,
       fecha_abordaje,
       0 as seq
from t_evaluacion_embarazada
union
select ...,
       fecha_abordaje,
       0 as seq
from t_evaluacion_menor3meses
union
select ...,
       fecha_abordaje,
       1 as seq
from t_seguimiento
order by seq, fecha_abordaje
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que agregar despues de las sentencias de `WHERE` la sentencia `ORDER BY` en las consultas que quieres ordernar.

```
FROM dean_eapg.t_evaluacion_mayor5
WHERE t_evaluacion_mayor5.codigo_descripcion_situacion::text > '1'::text
ORDER BY t_evaluacion_mayor5.FECHA
```